# Is it feasible to get into amateur sports as an adult?

Tags: amateur

It seems that even most amateur sports groups are made up of people who played on at least a related Varsity team or multiple years of Junior Varsity in school. Some might not be at peak fitness, but these athletes have had years of sport-specific coaching on technique.

As someone who did not do any sports in school, is it feasible to join an amateur sports team as an adult? How much training would be necessary before one stops being a complete liability to the team (or losing constantly in an individual sport)? Should people who didn't do sports in school stick to running and weight lifting?

I personally have been doing weight lifting with a trainer for a few years and running, if it matters, but a more general answer is appreciated.

Comment: Hello! I did not realize there was a separate sports stack exchange, and someone else migrated this question here. I'm not sure it fits here: it seems this stack exchange is for technical questions and sports teams. Please suggest any additional tags I should add if this is the right place.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE - while it's true a lot of our questions are about technical/rules issues, we're not exclusively about that; to quote from our [on-topic page](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), "Sports Stack Exchange is for participants, hobbyists, and fans of all sports and forms of competitive physical activity" and this question clearly falls within that. Not sure if there are any particularly relevant tags, but the community may find some!

Comment: @PhilipKendall I’m the migrating mod from fitness, glad to see this is a good fit here. This seemed like a good candidate for a “good subjective” sort of answer.

Comment: It really depends on where you live. I used to live in an area where ice hockey was really popular, and I skated with people with no prior experience (like myself when I started), people who'd played recreationally for 20 years, people with college experience, even one guy who had previously played professionally in Germany.

Comment: I think the assumptions in your first paragraph are not common. Most people playing sport after education are doing it more the enjoyment and social aspect of a sports club than because they couldnt quite make it at an elite level. And they are usually doing it with a complete lack of 'sport-specific coaching on technique'.

Comment: @TheFootsie I'm definitely not suggesting that people who do club sports "couldn't make it". It's more that most people in my circles are expected to do a sport in high school, just like 50+% of middle class families make their kids play an instrument. Some hate sports, some even competed in college or even went pro briefly, but most did sports with a coach at some point.

Comment: Perhaps the tone of my comment was unclear, your question reads as though you are unsure about taking up a new sport as an adult because you are concerned that you wont be good enough. If that is your concern you dont need to worry, almost all clubs are very welcoming of beginners.

Answer (score 1):

> How much training would be necessary before one stops being a complete liability to the team (or losing constantly in an individual sport)?

In my experience, this depends almost entirely on the individual and their affinity for the sport. I've seen "untrained" adults come into sports clubs and rapidly (1-2 years, sometimes less than that) progress past other people who have been playing the same sport for years. I've also seen adults come in and "bump along at the bottom".

> Should people who didn't do sports in school stick to running and weight lifting?

**You should do what makes you happy**, it's not all about being competitive. Some of those people above who "bumped along at the bottom" have been great long-term members of the club, even if they didn't contribute to the league results.

Comment: What distinguished the people who bumped along at the bottom from those who were able to contribute?